# How to append value in an existing object without change the first object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

My javascript code like this :

```
var data= {product_id: 4, name: 'nike'}
console.log(data)

var dataNew = data
dataNew.id = 1

console.log(dataNew)
```

Demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/69dw8dv1/

I append value in the object like that

The result of console.log(data) and console.log(dataNew) is there exist id

I want var data is no id

So there is only var dataNew that has id

How can I do it?

Comment: `delete data.id` but this would delete the property from `dataNew` too. You need to clone the object before doing that.

Comment: @Werner, How can I clone the object?

Comment: `const dataNew = Object.assign({}, data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, object references are assigned, instead of the object values, unless the object is of primitive data types.

That's why `dataNew` and `data` refers to the same object when you do this:

```
var dataNew = data;
```

To prevent this, you need to create a copy of `data` like this:

```
var dataNew = Object.assign({}, data);
```

Now, the changes in `dataNew` won't affect `data`.